# Why does my sorting of ASP.NET Telerik RadGrid columns not work? The RadGrid is cleared and the rows disappear when clicking a column header

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

### What I'm trying to Achieve

I have a ASP.NET Telerik RadGrid. I want it to sort by column when I press a column header.

### Problem

When I press a column header to sort the grid, the grid is cleared and all rows disappear and after the text "No records to display" is shown.

After pressing the Status column header:
[image]

### Code

The .aspx code (template):

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/MyApp.Master" Async="True" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SecondLine.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyApp_Service_WEB.SecondLine" %>

<asp:Content id="SecondLineContent" ContentPlaceHolderId="content" runat="server">

    <style>

        .small-top-margin {
            margin-top: 0.5em;
        }
        
        .medium-top-margin {
            margin-top: 1em;
        }

        .medium-bottom-margin {
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        .vertical-center {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .auto-width {
            width: auto;
            min-width: auto;
            max-width: auto;
        }
        
    </style>

    <!-- Search section  -->
    <div class="col-12">

        <fieldset>

            <legend>
                <asp:Literal id="lSearchTitle" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, SearchCase %>" runat="server" />
            </legend>

            <div class="col-12">

                <!-- Status select  -->
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:Label id="lbStatusSelect" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Status %>"/>
                </div>
                <div class="row small-top-margin">
                    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlStatusSelect" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="select-md auto-width" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </div>

                <!-- Check boxes -->
                <div class="row medium-top-margin vertical-center">
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chPersonalInjury" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <asp:Label id="lbPersonalInjury" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, PersonalInjury %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
            
                <div class="row vertical-center">
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chRiskForPersonalInjury" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <asp:Label id="lbRiskForPersonalInjury" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, RiskForPersonalInjury %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
            
                <div class="row vertical-center">
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chCompensationDemand" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <asp:Label id="lbCompensationDemand" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, CompensationDemand %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
            
                <div class="row vertical-center">
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chSecondLine" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <asp:Label id="lbSecondLine" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, SecondLine %>" runat="server" />
                </div>

                <div class="row medium-top-margin medium-bottom-margin">
                    <asp:Button id="btnSearch" UseSubmitBehaviour="True" CssClass="button grey" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, ButtonSearch %>" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"></asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:button id="btnCancel" UseSubmitBehaviour="True" CssClass="button grey" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, ButtonCancel %>" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"></asp:button>
                </div>

            </div>


        </fieldset>

    </div>


    <!-- Result section -->
    <div class="col-12">

        <fieldset>

            <legend>
                <asp:Literal id="lResultTitle" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, BlockHeaderText2 %>" runat="server" />
            </legend>

            <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgCases" CssClass="data-table bottomSpace" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Skin="Metro"
                            ForeColor="#333333" CellPadding="4" ShowFooter="false" GridLines="None" Width="100%"
                            AllowSorting="True"
                            OnNeedDataSource="rgCases_OnNeedDataSource"
                            OnSortCommand="rgCases_Sorting"
                            OnItemDataBound="rgCases_OnItemDataBound"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rgCases_OnSelectedIndexChanged">

                <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="True" Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true" Scrolling-SaveScrollPosition="true"
                    Scrolling-AllowScroll="true" Scrolling-UseStaticHeaders="true" EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
                </ClientSettings>

                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="CaseId, ArticleNumber, ArticleDescription, CaseType, Status, Language, Created" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true">

                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="CaseId">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="CaseIdHeader" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, CaseNumberColumn %>"></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="CaseIdItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CaseId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="10em" />
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="10em" />
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="ArticleNumber">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="ArticleNumberHeader" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, ArticleNr %>"></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="ArticleNumberItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ArticleNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="10em" />
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="10em" />
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ArticleDescription" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Global, Description %>" UniqueName="ArticleDescription" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="ArticleDescription" />

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CaseType" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Global, CaseType %>" UniqueName="CaseType" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Global, Status %>" UniqueName="Status" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Status" />

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Language">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="LanguageHeader" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Country %>"></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="LanguageItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Language") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="5em" />
                            <HeaderStyle Width="5em" />
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Created">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="CreatedHeader" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, CreatedOn %>"></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="CreatedItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Created") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="13em" />
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="13em" />
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>

                </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>

        </fieldset>

    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

The .cs code (code behind):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MyApp_WCF.CASEDB;
using MyApp_WCF.DataContracts;
using MyApp_WCF.Helpers;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace MyApp_Service_WEB
{
    public partial class SecondLine : BasePage
    {

        public List<WorkFlowRowStatus> StatusList { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateControls();
                SetControlDefaultValues();
                InitCasesLoad();
            }
        }

        private void PopulateControls() {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(PopulateStatusSelect));
        }

        private void SetControlDefaultValues() {
            chSecondLine.Checked = true;
        }

        private async Task PopulateStatusSelect() {
            await LoadStatusList();
            ddlStatusSelect.DataSource = StatusList;
            ddlStatusSelect.DataBind();
        }

        private async Task LoadStatusList() {
            if(StatusList != null)
                return;

            SemiStaticSettingsCache semiStaticSettingsCache = new SemiStaticSettingsCache();
            StatusList = (await semiStaticSettingsCache.GetWorkFlowRowStatusesAsync(GetSetting().UserInformation.GetCultureNameByUserLanguage()))
                .Select(s => s).ToList();

            WorkFlowRowStatus emptyOption = new WorkFlowRowStatus{
                Id = -1,
                Description = ""
            };
            StatusList.Insert(0, emptyOption);
        }

        private void InitCasesLoad()
        {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(SearchCases));
        }

        protected async void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            await SearchCases();
        }

        protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {

        }

        protected void rgCases_Sorting(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridTableView caseTable = e.Item.OwnerTableView;

            GridSortExpression sortExpression = new GridSortExpression
            {
                FieldName = e.SortExpression,
                SortOrder = e.NewSortOrder
            };

            caseTable.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(sortExpression);
            caseTable.Rebind();
        }

        protected void rgCases_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void rgCases_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SecondLineTableRow selectedCase = GetSelectedGridRow();
            int? caseId = selectedCase.CaseId;
            Response.Redirect($"WorkWithCase.aspx?chid={caseId}");
        }

        protected void rgCases_OnNeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            rgCases.DataSource = new List<SecondLineTableRow>();
        }

        private void SetGridRows(List<SecondLineTableRow> rows)
        {
            rgCases.DataSource = rows;
            rgCases.DataBind();
        }

        private SecondLineTableRow GetSelectedGridRow()
        {
            try
            {
                GridItem selectedItem = rgCases.SelectedItems[0];
                SecondLineTableRow selectedRow = GetRowFromGridItem(selectedItem);
                return selectedRow;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private SecondLineTranslations GetSecondLineTranslations() {
            return new SecondLineTranslations(
                GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "PersonalInjury") as string,
                GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "RiskForPersonalInjury") as string,
                GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "CompensationDemand") as string,
                GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "SecondLine") as string,
                GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "Repair") as string
            );
        }

        private async Task SearchCases() {
            SecondLineTranslations secondLineTranslations = GetSecondLineTranslations();
            SecondLineRepository secondLineRepo = new SecondLineRepository(secondLineTranslations);
            SecondLineSearchCriteria searchCriteria = CreateSearchCriteria();
            List<SecondLineTableRow> cases = await secondLineRepo.GetSecondLines(searchCriteria);
            SetGridRows(cases);
        }

        private SecondLineSearchCriteria CreateSearchCriteria() {
            return new SecondLineSearchCriteria(
                GetSetting().UserInformation.Language,
                personalInjury: chPersonalInjury.Checked,
                riskForPersonalInjury: chRiskForPersonalInjury.Checked,
                compensationDemand: chCompensationDemand.Checked,
                secondLine: chSecondLine.Checked,
                status: GetSelectedStatus()
            );
        }

        private WorkFlowRowStatus.Type? GetSelectedStatus() {
            if(EmptyStatusSelected())
                return null;

            WorkFlowRowStatus.Type selectedStatus = (WorkFlowRowStatus.Type) Enum.Parse(typeof(WorkFlowRowStatus.Type), ddlStatusSelect.SelectedValue);
            return selectedStatus;
        }

        private bool EmptyStatusSelected() {
            int selectedIndex = ddlStatusSelect.SelectedIndex;
            return selectedIndex <= 0;
        }

        private SecondLineTableRow GetRowFromGridItem(GridItem item) {
            
            return new SecondLineTableRow(
                GetValueFromColumn<string>(item, "ArticleNumber"),
                GetValueFromColumn<string>(item, "ArticleDescription"),
                GetValueFromColumn<string>(item, "CaseType"),
                GetValueFromColumn<string>(item, "Status"),
                GetValueFromColumn<string>(item, "Language"),
                GetValueFromColumn<DateTime>(item, "Created"),
                GetValueFromColumn<int?>(item, "CaseId")
            );
        }

        private T GetValueFromColumn<T>(GridItem item, string column) {
            var itemValue = item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[item.ItemIndex][column];
            var x = item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[item.ItemIndex];
            return (T) itemValue;
        }

        private DateTime GetDateTimeFromColumn(GridItem item, string column) {
            var itemValueStr = item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[item.ItemIndex][column] as string;
            return DateTime.Parse(itemValueStr);
        }

    }
}
```

### Question

Why are the rows removed when pressing a column header? Why doesn't the sorting work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The rebind is most likely the issue, though according to telerik examples you should also check that the expression isn't already set.

From the examlple at: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/sorting/basic-sorting/defaultcs.aspx

```
    protected void RadGrid1_SortCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //Default sort order Descending
        if (this.CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            if (!e.Item.OwnerTableView.SortExpressions.ContainsExpression(e.SortExpression))
            {
                GridSortExpression sortExpr = new GridSortExpression();
                sortExpr.FieldName = e.SortExpression;
                sortExpr.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending;

                e.Item.OwnerTableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(sortExpr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Rebinding the grid does not seem to be needed and may be what is causing the content to disappear, try removing it.